# How to decrement each element of a device_vector by a constant?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to use `thrust::transform` to decrement a constant value from each element of a `device_vector`. As you can see, the last line is incomplete. I'm trying to decrement from all elements the constant `fLowestVal` but dont know how exactly.

```
thrust::device_ptr<float> pWrapper(p);
thrust::device_vector<float> dVector(pWrapper, pWrapper + MAXX * MAXY);
float fLowestVal = *thrust::min_element(dVector.begin(), dVector.end(),thrust::minimum<float>());

// XXX What goes here?
thrust::transform(...);
```

Another question: Once I do my changes on the `device_vector`, will the changes apply also to the `p` array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can decrement a constant value from each element of a `device_vector` by combining `for_each` with a placeholder expression:

```
#include <thrust/functional.h>
...
using thrust::placeholders;
thrust::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), _1 -= val);
```

The unusual `_1 -= val` syntax means to create an unnamed functor whose job is to decrement its first argument by `val`.  `_1` lives in the namespace `thrust::placeholders`, which we have access to via the `using thrust::placeholders` directive.

You could also do this by combining `for_each` or `transform` with a custom functor you provided yourself, but it's more verbose.

Comment: WOW jared that's what i was looking for! could you elaborate about the preformance of the for_each function?

Comment: @igalk Functions like these are bandwidth limited. The performance should be "as fast as you can read and write"

Answer (score 0):

One option which could be useful in a wide range of contexts is to use one of Thrust's fancy iterators as an argument of `thrust::transform`. Here, you would do so along with the `thrust::minus` binary function object, like this:

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
...
thrust::transform(vec.begin(),
                  vec.end(),
                  thrust::make_constant_iterator(value),
                  vec.begin(),
                  thrust::minus<float>());
```

The documentation for fancy iterators can be found [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__fancyiterator.html#ga0510c773bef5408b233245d5be5dab70).

Comment: Thanks to eesweng for pointing out a previous mistake in the ordering of arguments.